# Can't figure out how to modify lists based on variables (example Objects[variable[variable2]])

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple game for a project, I need the game to be able to handle multiple rectangle objects (probably around 10-15 but obviously I dont want a function for each one).

The problem I have encountered is that I want Python to access for example
Objects is a list containing all rectangles (currently Rct0 and Rct1) so I want a function to be able to modify/access Objects[variable[variable2]], so lets say I want to change Colour of Rectangle 1 in Objects, how can I do that ? When I try to 'nest' it, it always throws an error.
I have included my code below.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

cWhite = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
cGray = pygame.Color (70,70,70)
cRed = pygame.Color (255,0,0)
cBlue = pygame.Color (0,0,255)
cCyan = pygame.Color (0,255,255)
cGreen = pygame.Color (0,255,0)


global cycleCount, longCycle, pause
cycleCount = 0
longCycle = 0
pause = False
global x, y, cID, rID, objCount
global Objects, Rct0, Rct1
Rct0 = [0,0,0,0,0]
Rct1 = [0,0,0,0,0]
Objects = [[Rct0],[Rct1]]


def spawnRandomizer():
    global x, y, cID, rID
    x = 440
    y = random.randrange(60,440)
    cID = random.choice(colours)
    rID = 0
    Objects[rID] = [x, y, cID, 1, 1]
    print(Objects[rID])


def drawRectangle():
    global x, y, cID, rID
    Objects[rID] = [x, y, cID, 1, 1]
    pygame.draw.rect(Window, cGreen, (Rct0[0], Rct0[1], 50, 50))


#FRAME LOOP

while True:
    Window=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Rectangle generator')
    Window.fill(cWhite)

    if cycleCount == 0:
        spawnRandomizer();
    drawRectangle();






    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    if cycleCount == 30:
        cycleCount = 0

    if longCycle == 300:
        longCycle = 0

    cycleCount = cycleCount + 1
    longCycle = longCycle + 1
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I've found that you can do Objects[0][1] or Objects[variable1][variable2] so I solved my problem. I just could not find this anywhere for some reason before.**